# Firebase Database Saving Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently using Firebase for email and password Authentication. My problem is how do I create the same UID for the 'Email and password authentication section' and the 'Database' section. They appear to have two separate UID. On a note, I used push() for the database section to save the data. For the email and password I used the simple devdoc createemailandpassword function.

[image: This is the Authentication section UID]

[image: This is the Database section UID]

Answer (score 1):

After using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method, you will authenticate the user and, the user will have an unique id for him.

The `push()` generates a random id in the database.

You need to get the `userid` and then add it to the database:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var uid,useremail;
if (user != null) {
uid = user.uid;
useremail = user.email;
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref().child("users").child(uid).set({
email:useremail
  });
}
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 1):

The UID in the Auth panel is generated by Firebase after authentication, when you get this in the callback, save a "user" dictionary under that UID, under a "Users" node. I'm not sure what coding language you're using but in iOS (swift) it would look something like this. (It may not be perfect but you should get the idea).

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
     //Check that there's no error and grab the user.uid property and call the below function after creating a user dictionary
})

func registerNewUserInDatabase(dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>, uid: String) {
    userRef.child(uid).updateChildValues(dictionary)
}
```